# How to make the YouTube Embed consistent?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-iframe-api

I noticed that the interface of the YouTube Embed's controls change as per view.

Here is how it looks in mobile view:
[image: YouTube embed controls in mobile view]

and Here's how its controls look in normal view:

[image: Embed in desktop view]

I want the controls to look the same ( I want the first video's controls to look like the second one ).
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is the HTML for that video:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="232px" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/6kAvCSMkYEI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: How you embed it? Have youtube video with custom player, then style it as you want

Comment: I just edited the post with the HTML code.

Comment: Then you can't change iFrame content in any way